# Magento Attribute Issue

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

I have a site where they want to tag a product as a "Trend" and show a star on the Product page and on the category page.  I for the life of me cant figure out the best way to do this.  There isnt a hidden attribute to key off.

Has anyone done something like it or have some pointers?

Thanks

Comment: Add attribute trend to product that takes radio button value. If this is checked then a product should display Trend related star.in your code now check value for this attribute and apply code

Answer (score 0):

Sorry All,

```
I was not thinking when I wrote this.  All I did was add a Yes/No Attribute in the set called trend_setter.  Then in the list.phtml I looked for
```

$_product->_data['trend_setter'] == 1

in the product loop and I show a white or black star based on this field